# Cordova, iOS,Iframes and external links

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I have a problem that lies at the intersection of **Cordova, iOS, iFrames** and external links. 
Why use an iFrame? Because I need to include an external web site within an area of a web page. In cases where I can use the entire window, inAppBrowser works fine. The site that is loaded inside the iFrame has external links. These link open normally in a separate window when using all other clients (eg. Browser) -- but in iOS a separate browser window is not opened -- even when `window.open(target, "_blank")` is used. Instead, the site is opened in the same app window, replacing the app and leaving no way to return to it.

I've considered various ways of communicating with the iFrame, but communication is blocked because the parent has the origin `file://` while the iFrame has the origin `https://`.

As a last resort, I'm considering using "universal links" or a registered URL scheme for the app to redirect these calls to a different app that would load the content of the external site in a new app window... but that might not work, and there is a significant amount of work to do before I can even test that approach.

I've done much searching for solutions to this problem but have not come across anything that directly relates to it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.